# How can I databind a gridview to an arraylist in .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, data-binding

How can I databind a gridview to an arraylist in .NET?

I am using .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

In place of arraylist use generic class BindingList. It will allow you to bind this list in two direcions to DataGridView. So your change in BindingList will be reflected in DGV and vice versa.

Here you have more information about BindingList class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do would be to build an alternate collection;  try a List<> or a BindingList<>.